# Why does OpenGL give handles to objects instead of pointers?

Tags: opengl, uniqueidentifier

The OpenGL tradition is to let the user manipulate OpenGL objects using an unsigned int handle. Why not just give a pointer instead? What are the advantages of unique IDs over pointers?

Comment: Avoids problems with different pointer sizes on different systems and rendering via network (e.g. GLX).

Comment: I do like your answer, but are GL ids really guaranteed to have the same size across implementations?

Comment: No they just specify minimum bits size (which is 32). But since ids are auto-increment it isn't a problem (can safely assign as long as not hitting overflow), and overflowing 32bits will require enormous amount of id creation, so I don't think it would be possible. GLX protocol itself however have very strict spec that provides opcodes and actual sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*TL;DR: OpenGL IDs don't map bijectively to memory locations. A single OpenGL ID may refer to multiple memory locations at the same time. Also OpenGL has been designed to work for distributed rendering architectures (like X11) as well, and given an indirect context programs running on different machines may use the same OpenGL context.*

OpenGL has been designed as an architecture and display system agnostic API. When OpenGL was first developed this happened in light of client-server display architectures (like X11). If you look into the OpenGL specification, even of modern OpenGL-4 it refers to clients and servers.

However in a client/server architectures pointers make no sense. For one the address space of the server is not accessible to the clients without jumping some hoops. And even if you set up a shared memory mapping, the addresses of objects are not the same for client and server. Add to this that on architectures like X11 a single indirect OpenGL context can be used by multiple clients, that may even run on different machines. Pointers simply don't work for that.

Last but not least the OpenGL object model is highly abstract and the OpenGL drawing model is asynchonous Say I do the following:

```
id = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(id)

glTexStorage(…)

glTexSubImage(image_a)
draw_something()

glTexSubImage(image_b)
draw_someting_b()
```

When the end of this little snippet has reached, actually nothing at all may have been drawn *yet*, because no synchronization point has been reached (glFinish, glReadPixels, a buffer swap). Note the two calls to glTexSubImage, which happen on the same id. When the pixels are finally put to the framebuffer, there two different images to be sourced from a single texture ID, because OpenGL guarantees you, that things will appear as if things were drawn synchronously. So at the end of a drawing batch a single object ID may refer to a whole collection of different data sets with different locations in memory.

Answer (score 1):

My first consideration - having pointers would make programmers wonder if they can operate with them in a pointer-arithmetic way, e.g. by pointing to a middle of a texture to update it or something like that. Maybe even more crazy things, such as patching shaders code on-the-fly. That all sounds like a whole new cool degree of freedom, unless you think of additional complications caused by tampering with highly efficient and optimized GPU "black-box" way of operation.

For example - consider inner workings of GPU memory allocation. Just like with OS - pointers you get from OS are not the real "physical" ones, OS memory manager can move things around behind the scenes while keeping the pointers the same (f.e. swapping to HDD). In that case IDs are just the same - GPU can optimize and pack entities with even more freedom, while keeping the nice facade of them being available at 1-2-3.

Another example - OpenGL is not actually the same across manufacturers. In fact OpenGL is just a description of API, where each vendor can make his own implementation the way it works best for him. For example there's no rule on hot to store texture mipmaps, aligned, or interleaved or whatever. Having pointers to a texture would lure developers into tampering with mipmaps, which would cause a lot of trouble to support various implementations or force all the implementations to become strictly unified, which again is a bad idea for performance.

Comment: with the old win16 handles were pointers where programmers tried to do direct manipulation even though all documentation said not to, this led to problems when microsoft tried to update the API

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL device (GPU) may have its own memory with its own address space, independent of the host (CPU) memory system.  (Think of a discrete video card with its own onboard RAM.)  The host can't (directly) access that memory, so it's not possible to have a pointer to it.

It's best to think of the GPU as a whole separate computer; it's actually possible to do OpenGL over a network, with a program running on one computer rendering graphics on the video card in another.  When you set up your textures and buffers, you're basically uploading data to the GL device for its own internal use.

Comment: Yes but GL isn't only GPU-side. I'm quite sure each handle have at least some data on main memory too, if not a full copy (which is even more likely).

Comment: @keltar: You're forgetting about GLX.

Comment: @datenwolf I'm not. Maybe I didn't made myself clear. Returning server-side address is possible; client side wouldn't be able to access it, of course. I'm not saying that it is better; just two different approaches, and I don't think any one of them is particularly better than another. And if there is no good reason to change things - they shouldn't be changed.

Comment: @keltar: You're stuck thinking that the server has to run on a system that uses a linear address layout at all. But there are computer architectures, for which there is no such thing as a continuous, large, single address space. Hint: Lisp-Machine.

Comment: @datenwolf I never said that. If addresses were allowed, implementation may return the closest to its native representation it could; if there is no point in doing that, it still could fallback and use autoincrement id or any other type of unique number that it could understand. It wouldn't break things. But amount of potential speed increase (slightly reduced lookups) isn't correlating too well with increased complexity.

Comment: @keltar: Here's another reason for not using pointers: The `glGen…` functions only allocate the handle, but not the actual object. The size of the object is not known until it has been allocated/populated with data (`glTexImage` / `glTexStorage` / `glBufferData`), but the location in a linear address space depends on the size of the data (due to address space fragmentation). That being said: With the requirement of using `glGen…` for obtaining handles with OpenGL-3-core+ and OpenGL-ES some implementations actually give you the pointer to an internal data structure casted to GLuint as handle.