# How to determine pointer size preprocessor C

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on a software implementation of OpenGL, and OpenGL seems to require that I return 32-bit pointers. To save time, I am putting this into a C equivalent of map with 64-bit systems in order to retrieve 64-bit pointers from 32-bit psuedo-addresses. However, on 32-bit systems, this would cause a hassle, and so I should just use the pointer verbatim.

Here is basically what I want to do in my shared header:

```
#if <64-bit>
    #include <search.h>
    extern void * pointerTable;
    typedef struct {
          int key;
          void* value;
    } intPtrMap;

    inline int compar(const void *l, const void *r) {
        const intPtrMap *lm = l;
        const intPtrMap *lr = r;
        return lm->key - lr->key;
    }

    inline uint32_t allocate(size) {
        void* result = malloc(size);
        intPtrMap *a = malloc(sizeof(intStrMap));
        a->key = (uint32_t) result;
        a->value = result;
        tsearch(a, &pointerTable, compar);
        return (uint32_t) result;
    }

    inline int getPtr(ptr) {
        intPtrMap *find_a = malloc(sizeof(intPtrMap));
        find_a->key = ptr;
        void *r = tfind(find_a, &root, compar);
        return (*(intPtrMap**)r)->value;
    }
#else
    inline uint32_t allocate(size) {
        return (uint32_t) malloc(size);
    }

    inline uint32_t getPtr(ptr) {
        return (uint32_t) ptr;
    }
#endif
```

Any suggestions on how to do the first if?

Comment: How about using a plain `if` and seeing if the optimizer is clever enough to remove dead code? I'd expect it to be.

Comment: `a->key = (uint32_t) result;` is likely not unique. Malloc could even return `(uint32_t) result == 0` every time and be perfectly standard conform.

Comment: Under Linux how about simply using 32bit addresses? mmap() has a flag `MAP_32BIT` to allocate memory in the first 2GB of address space. Or use `MAP_FIXED` with a low enough address. Both would ensure the upper 32bits of any pointer are 0 bits and you can use them without having to map them.

Comment: Aside: To avoid `int` overflow with `lm->key - lr->key;` and _undefined behavior_, use `(lm->key > lr->key) - (lm->key < lr->key);`

Comment: Instead of `#if <64-bit>`, perhaps `#if UINTPTR_MAX > 0xFFFFFFFF`?

Comment: `intPtrMap a = malloc(sizeof(intStrMap));` is certainly invalid code.  What is code, @Lightning Creations,  trying to do here?

Comment: @Quentin I came up with a solution. I prefer to use preprocessor in the case of newer compilers with worse optimizers, such as one that is being made for the SNES that is going to be able to run this.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow 1. There is under a 1/1000000 chance of collision for each new allocation. I worked it out.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow 2. This is made to be cross platform, not just Linux-based.

Comment: @chux 1. I will do that! Thank you.

Comment: @chux 2. I'll add that in on the next run!

Comment: @chux 3. Typo. Sorry. That should be a pointer.

Comment: The bad old days use configure scripts that compile code using `printf("%d\n, sizeof(void*))` to define a `POINTER_SIZE` variable for the preprocessor. *shiver*.

Comment: Are you sure OpenGL uses 32-bit pointers and not 32-bit IDs? Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24694186/5264491) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24690014/5264491)?

Comment: @IanAbbott I would use IDs, but just using memory addresses seems to be easier since I'm not actually using the graphics card at all for this.

Comment: The code does not smell right. Are you sure this is needed? You do not have types for your parameters.

Comment: Also a typo that got fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to determine pointer size preprocessor C (?)

To determine *pointer size* in a portable fashion is tricky.

**Various pointers sizes**

It is not uncommon to have a pointer to a function wider than a pointer to an object or `void*`.
Pointers to `int` `char`, `struct` can be of different sizes, although that is rare.
So let us reduce the task to determine `void *` pointer size.

**Pre-processor math**

PP math is limited, so code needs to be careful.  Let us stay with integer math.

**`(u)intptr_t`**

The optional types [`(u)intptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1464174/2410359), which are very commonly available, are useful here.  They allow conversion of a `void *` to an integer and then to an equivalent `void*`.

Although the integer type size may differ from the pointer type, that, I assert is rare and detectable with [`_Static_assert`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3385515/2410359) from C11.

---

Following will handle many C11 platforms.  Useful ideas toward a general solution.

```
#include <stdint.h>

// C11
_Static_assert(sizeof (void*) == sizeof (uintptr_t), 
    "TBD code needed to determine pointer size");

// C99 or later
#if UINTPTR_MAX == 0xFFFF
  #define PTR16
#elif UINTPTR_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFF
  #define PTR32
#elif UINTPTR_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu
  #define PTR64
#else
  #error TBD pointer size
#endif
```

---

[Edit 2021]

With [Is there any way to compute the width of an integer type at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359), code could use, at compile time, the below to find the width of `uintptr_t`.

```
/* Number of bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<k)-1 where 0 <= k < 2040 */
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))
#define UINTPTR_MAX_BITWIDTH IMAX_BITS(UINTPTR_MAX)
```

Comment: "`It is not uncommon to have a pointer to a function wider than a pointer to an object or `void*`.`" -- It's certainly permitted by the C standard, but in my experience it is quite uncommon.

Comment: [Why are function pointers and data pointers incompatible in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12358843/2410359) goes into issues including size.

Comment: Yes, I understand the issues. My point is merely that on most modern systems, all pointers are the same size.

Comment: @KeithThompson "on most modern systems, ..." I'd say _most_ modern systems are embedded ones, billions per year.  Lots of varieties there.  IAC, I agree most are the same, but unequal is not rare and deserves consideration for portable code.

Comment: Interesting point. Can you point to some examples of embedded systems where different C pointer types have different sizes? (Regardless, I fully agree that code intended to be portable shouldn't assume that different pointer types have the same size. It's usually not that difficult to avoid making any assumptions.)

Comment: @KeithThompson "point to some examples" --> not well.  My direct embedded experience ~2005 - ~2018 included non-compliant C with small PICs (8-bit RAM data pointers and 16-bit address constant and function pointers (always "even")) to DOS-like 16-bit `void *` and 32-bit function pointers.  In one way, I've divorced object and function pointers from being the same for so long now that I simply write code that accommodates the difference, needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using other questions on StackOverflow and also a solution from somebody on Discord, I have cobbled together this solution:

```
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
    #if _WIN64
        #define PTR64
    #else
        #define PTR32
    #endif
#elif __GNUC__
    #if __x86_64__ || __ppc64__
        #define PTR64
    #else
        #define PTR32
    #endif
#elif UINTPTR_MAX > UINT_MAX
    #define PTR64
#else
    #define PTR32
#endif
```

This should be able to reliably determine 64-bit or 32-bit pointer usage in preprocessor.

Comment: You can't use `sizeof` in a preprocessor expression.

Comment: It compiles fine, but since I have seen better things in other comments, I will replace it.

Comment: Good idea! Putting that in now.

Comment: Actually, your `UINTPTR_MAX > 0xFFFFFFFF` was more explicit than my `UINTPTR_MAX > UINT_MAX` suggestion. (Sorry I deleted my comment earlier.)

Comment: But I'm really comparing it to the UINT max for storage, so this is better.

Comment: `UINTPTR_MAX > UINT_MAX` --> The goal is not then to determine if the pointer is 64-bit, but if it wider than `unsigned`.

Comment: And since uint32_t (uint) is 32-bit, bigger would be 64-bit.

Comment: This code is a whole lot of wishful thinking. The real world is not so kind.

Comment: @LightningCreations `uint32_t (uint)` is unclear.  Also note that `UINT_MAX` may be as small as 0xFFFF as used in `UINTPTR_MAX > UINT_MAX`.

Comment: In that case, I would need to act as if the pointer were 32-bit anyway, since truncation would kill my system.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question.
But I have some new idea here.

```cpp
#define SIZEOF_POINTER (UINTPTR_MAX / 255 % 255)

#if SIZEOF_POINTER == 8
// on 64 bit system
#elif SIZEOF_POINTER == 4
// on 32 bit system
#elif ...
#endif
```

The code can works on 8/16/32/.../1024 bit system.

The mathematic behind this solution is really simple.
Treat UINTPTR_MAX as a 256 based number.
It can be present as （255,255,255,255...), then divide it by 255, we got (1,1,1,1,...).

Then the final question is count how many 1s in the number.
That's really simple, on decimal we have 1000000... % 9 = 1.
Surely it's the same here. we have (1,0,0,0,...) % 255 = 1, and (1,0,1,0...) % 255 = number of 1s.
The only restriction here is the number of 1s cannot more than 255.

And thanks to UINTPTR_MAX(c++11). Before this, we always do a tons of work for this.